# Why doesn't trading luxury resources seem to work?

Tags: civilization-6

I made a trade deal with another civilization to get a luxury resource (I traded a silver, which I have 2 of, for truffles, which I don't have any of). However that didn't seem to increase my amenities at all and on the resource report I don't see any difference from trade. Even when I tried to do a deal where I bought a luxury resource for gold, I didn't see any change. What is going on here?

Comment: Yeah I am still trying to figure this out... how many cities do you have?  You need 1 amenity for every four cities, so I THINK if you loss one and gained one your net is 0.  I have 10 cities and my capital is +3 from luxury while the city near it is 0... don't understand.

Answer (score 13):

**TL;DR Changes in amenities won't show up until you hit the next turn button.**

In Civ 6, each luxury gives you 4 amenities, and extra copies of a particular luxury don't give you more amenities.  According to page 50 of the manual:

> Only one source of a specific luxury provides amenities, shared with the four neediest cities in your empire.

You don't have precise control over which cities get which amenities, and "neediest" isn't defined anywhere, so I don't know exactly where those amenities are going to go.

In addition, it often takes to UI a long time to update things.  In this case, the engine that distributes amenities among your cities only runs after you click end turn, so the UI will definitely not reflect the new one until the next turn.

Comment: I find this 'wont happen till next turn' happens a lot in civ 6. For example killing off a civ and their captured cities growing again, ameneties showing up in cities after attaining them etc.

Answer (score 5):

The example DuckTapeAl gives is wrong.

When you have 8 cities and 2 silver, only 4 of your cities will get one amenities, the 'extra' silver is useless and won't do anything. However, when you trade like in his example, every city will get 1 amenity.

[source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=33CWv7A6Zng&list=PLQFX9B_9L4-k2jjbVPmdy7BwXql9pBGYl)

Comment: So what's the actual answer to the question?

Comment: Holy crap, would you look at that.  It even says it in the manual that no one reads. :P  I'll edit my answer.

Comment: One thing to note, though: Answers on SE have to stand on their own.  They can reference other answers, but they have to fully answer the question as well, and you don't really answer the question here.